# Both as a client and a server with GKSession

Tags: ios, client-server, gksession

Can I implement two GKSession, one as a client and the other as a server at the same time?
Is there a problem or any limitation to implement this connection with WiFi and Bluetooth?
Thanks!

Comment: I finally created two different sessions for both GKSessionModeServer and GKSessionModeClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GKSessionModePeer seems only can connect to another peer.
But I need to build up more complex network structure.
So I finally created two different sessions for both GKSessionModeServer and GKSessionModeClient.
And it can exist at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using GKSessionModePeer:

```
    gkSession = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:nil displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];
```

In peer mode, you act both as a client and as a server for other devices.

Comment: Is it able to connect to several peers at the same time?

Comment: Yes. "Note: The maximum size of a client-server game is 16 players." 
Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1

Comment: Gets very unreliable if more than two are connected with eachother.